# Python HTMLParser ignores data after ampersands

Tags: python, html, parsing

So I made a HTML parser in Python and I'm wanting it to print out all of the info between the div tags, but it seems that any data that comes without a space behind an ampersand doesn't want to print out. The code for the parser is:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser


class Parser(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.dataArray = []
        self.text = []
        self.inLink = False

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'div':
            self.inLink = True
            self.lasttag = tag

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.lasttag == 'div' and self.inLink:
            self.text.append(data)

    def handle_entityref(self, name):
        data = self.unescape('&amp;')
        self.text.append(data)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == 'div':
            self.inlink = False
            self.dataArray.append("".join(self.text))
            self.text = []
            for i in self.dataArray:
                if i == "":
                        self.dataArray.remove(i)


def time_to_parse(your_parser, text_to_parse):
        parser = your_parser
        decoded_text = parser.unescape(text_to_parse)
        parser.feed(decoded_text)
        unicode_data = your_parser.dataArray
        string_data = [i.encode('utf-8') for i in unicode_data]
        print(string_data)

time_to_parse(Parser(), '<div>ll&quot;ll&amp;mmmm</div>')
```

and this prints `'ll"ll&'`. If however I input `'<div>ll&quot;ll&amp; mmmm</div>'` as the text to parse (space after the ampersand) it prints out `'ll"ll& mmmm'` fine. I don't understand why it deals with the quotation marks and other entities fine but not ampersands, so I'm stuck on ideas :(

Comment: First off, I'm not familiar with the `HTMLParser` module. however, changing `self.text.append(data)` to `self.text.append(data + name)` on your `handle_entityref` function [seems to work](https://eval.in/private/0959c7bf0323a1).

Comment: Thanks @Himal, that works great. I still don't understand why, so if anyone can explain it, that would be really helpful.